# MAAS openstack install error, "Resolving timed out" on screen before I even start juju bootstrap

Tags: maas, openstack

I have been trying to install openstack without any success also following the setup instructions for autopilot. One thing I see is when running the setup is a resolving timed out error everytime. From the MAAS controller I am able to resolve itself as well as outside names IE www.google.com. I also have the forwarders set in the MAAS web ui for the nodes to point out. I have the MAAS server set up as DHCP and DNS.

setup for interfaces is:

```
# The primary network interface
auto em1 em2
iface em1 inet static
        address 10.1.6.5
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        network 10.1.0.0
        broadcast 10.1.255.255
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search blah.com

iface em2 inet static               <------MAAS Managed interface
        address 10.0.0.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255
        gateway 10.0.0.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search blah.com
```

Here is screenshot of the install error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: looking through command logs I see the following errors:   [WARNING: 03-08 09:45:10, utils.py:774] Generating random seed failed: Command 'sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/417da592-52b5-4d7e-b00c-6fc5d349a46d/IL"'' returned non-zero exit status 1